# GWT: Is adding the same Image twice not possible?

Tags: gwt

What I want to do is add units to a scale. One unit is an Image. So I decided to assign the URL to a global variable like this:

```
Image scaleUnit = new Image("example/url.xy");
```

And then I tried to add exactly this Object to the same FlowPanel twice like this:

```
examplepanel.add(scaleUnit);
examplepanel.add(scaleUnit);
```

This doesn't work as the result I get is only one Image inside of the FlowPanel. Why does this happen? Is it not possible to add the same Image twice or am I missing something?

Comment: No it not possible, any GWT widget, after is being add to panel is automatically detached from old one. It work same with DOM elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `Image` is a `Widget`; it is ultimately a wrapper around a DOM element. You cannot add such an element twice in the DOM tree and expect it to display twice: the second insertion will first remove it from where it currently is. DOM elements can be cloned, but not widgets. In brief: no you can't, you have to create 2 `Image` widgets.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not that familiar with DOM elements yet, so I didn't know. I'll accept this once I can (: